# scrolling after posting drupal ajax form

Tags: forms, ajax

I am working on an existing site which has a Drupal 8 multi-step form which uses Ajax

Upon submitting the form (on the final step) the page scrolls to the top where a thank you message has been inserted.

I want to change this so it scrolls to a fixed number of pixels bellow the top.

The code which applies the ajax behavior appears to be this

```
$form['actions'][$button->getKey()]['#ajax'] = [
                    'callback' => [$this, 'loadStep'],
                    'wrapper' => 'multistepform-wrapper',
                    'effect' => 'fade',
                ];
```

(note i have commented out the 'effect' => 'fade' line in the code to see if this alters the behavior and it does not).

The code which handles submitting on the form appears to be this

```
public function loadStep(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    $response = new AjaxResponse();

    //@todo: deal with deprecated drupal call.
    $messages = drupal_get_messages();
    if (!empty($messages)) {
        // Form did not validate, get messages and render them.
        $messages = [
            '#theme' => 'status_messages',
            '#message_list' => $messages,
            '#status_headings' => [
                'status' => $this->t('Status message'),
                'error' => $this->t('Error message'),
                'warning' => $this->t('Warning message'),
            ],
        ];
        $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#multistepform-messages-' . $this->uniqueIdSuffix(), $messages));
    } else {
        // Remove messages.
        $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#multistepform-messages-' . $this->uniqueIdSuffix(), ''));
    }

    // Update Form.
    $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#multistepform-wrapper-' . $this->uniqueIdSuffix(), $form['multistepform']));
    $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('body', 'trigger', ['pcaAjax']));

    return $response;
}
```

I have searched the codebase for javascripts with the 'pcaAjax' event and used chrome dev tools  breakpoints to see what javascript runs when the form is submitted and have concluded that the scrolling effect is handled by Drupals own javascript code.

How can i modify this form to give the behavior which i want?